# Form is Null in Dynamically created Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a Page Dynamically in ASP.NET and i want to load a Control inside the form but everytime I try to Add it to Page.Form.Controls the Form is null and gives out a NullReference

```
Page myPage = new Page();
FormAtt ctrl = (FormAtt)myPage.LoadControl("path/to/my/file.ascx");
myPage.Form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

---

I'm trying to do this because I have to parse the controls HTML , while firing the events and the logic inside the control,  into a string to fill a (really bad designed) String with HTML code, if I just call `ctrl.RenderControl(HtmlWriter)` the control will not render and it appears that the Events are not fired, i guessed i had to have a page to make the the event flow work, but I really didn't want to create a new aspx just for this.

Also, I'm sure the path is correct because I tested the same loadcontrol and becaus it doesn't raise an exception as it raises when I change the path to something non-existant. I can't redesign the code that assembles the HTML because it's just too much work and It's out of the scope of what i'm doing, the scope is not decided by me.

Comment: What you are doing seems odd.  Where exactly are you trying to create this new page from?  Why do you need to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like UserControl file path is not correct.

Could you try this

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath == "/" ? 
   string.Empty : HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

... (FormAtt)myPage.LoadControl(path + "/path/to/my/file.ascx");
```

If it still doesn't work, where is your file.ascx located related to your aspx page?

**Updated: myPage.Form will always be null. Please instantiate HtmlForm.**

```
Page myPage = new Page();
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
FormAtt ctrl = (FormAtt)myPage.LoadControl("path/to/my/file.ascx");
form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
myPage.Controls.Add(form);
```

Comment: the path is correct as i stated in my last edit, and also i don't have a physical aspx.

Answer (score 1):

`Page myPage = new Page();` is almost definitely not what you want here.  It sounds like you want to load your control into the current page, which would just be `Page.Controls.Add(ctrl)`.

Your title and question are both pretty clear about creating a Page though, so maybe you should explain the big picture more.

Comment: actually it's a little bit more complicated, i want to render the controls html into a variable while firing the event flow, and the html is not in a aspx but hardcoded - see the edit please.