# Overriding VerifyRenderingInServerForm on dynamically created Pages()

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I was having some problems regarding the creation of a Page dynamically I do :

```
p = New Page();
Page myPage = new Page();
FormAtt ctrl = (FormAtt)myPage.LoadControl("path/to/my/file.ascx");  // here lies the gridview of evil
myPage.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Problem is i receive

```
Control ... must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server
```

Ok, so I've found out that I Need to override the `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method to be able to call a formless page, But how can i override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` since i don't have a ASPX file.

---

ps: I have a related question and I don't know what to do, since they are different questions but the solution goes to the same problema , and I gave up on the last  solution - see : [Form is Null in Dynamically created Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946018/form-is-null-in-dynamically-created-pages)

Comment: You could try to create a custom `Page` that already overrides `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`. Then instead of `p = New Page();` this `p = New MyCustomPage();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a custom class which already overrides `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`:

```
 public partial class MyCustomPage : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {         
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = new MyCustomPage();
        FormAtt uc = (FormAtt)p.LoadControl("path/to/my/file.ascx");
        p.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, I was trying to avoid creating  new class because it's only going to be used in my Method.

Comment: hi, i need something similar but for Rendercontrol. how can i do it in a class instead of in the page?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your previous question. You need to add **HtmlForm** first. ASP.Net need a form tag in order to add controls to a page.

```
Page myPage = new Page();
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
FormAtt ctrl = (FormAtt)myPage.LoadControl("path/to/my/file.ascx");
form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
myPage.Controls.Add(form);
```

Comment: This worked too, but the resulting HTML contained a form, which was not needed

Answer (score 1):

i do it to render a component

```
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    Page p = new Page();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
    p.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Controls.Add(gv);
    form.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string j = stringWrite.ToString();
```